# Converting null value to 0 for all fields in MS access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, nul

I have a monthly sales table for different customers in ACCESS. The field names are in order Sales_201601, Sales_201602 etc. which changes dynamically with every data refresh.

I am looking for a SQL query which can automatically pick all columns with structure Sales_: and change null value to 0 in ACCESS.

I cannot put the field names individually, because table has many columns and field names changes over time. So need to write a code which changes dynamically with the field names.

I am new to MS access. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Blank is not the same as null. Null is not the same as 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access 2010 - Need to replace a null with a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922308/access-2010-need-to-replace-a-null-with-a-value)

Comment: Don't use a table this way. Use a crosstab query.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the fields individually:

```
update t
    set Sales_201601 = nz(Sales_201601, 0),
        Sales_201602 = nz(Sales_201602, 0)
    . . . ;
```

More importantly, you want to prevent this in the future.  The idea is to set the column to `not null` and set a default value.  I think the following works in MS Access:

```
alter table t alter Sales_201601 not null default 0;
```

You should do this when new columns are added into the table.

By the way, this would be much simpler if each column were on a separate row.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a code which can dynamically select all fields having keyword 'Sales' and then changing null values in those fields to zero.